# How to remove debug sessions from Firebase Analytics Dashboard?

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics-firebase

I'm making a new app and currently only I use it as it is in still in development stage.
It looks like Firebase Analytics measures every debug session as a new user because in the dashboard I see this:

[image]

I'm the only user so far, and I would like to turn of analytics for development/debug sessions.

How can I do so?

Comment: Some docs available here [https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview#ios+]

Answer (score 0):

Use two Firebase projects instead. This is what Firebase is intended for. One Production Firebase project and one for DEV / BETA / TESTING / TESTFLIGHT Firebase project.

Tip: You can assign a badge "Production" to your Firebase project for better organization of your projects.